# How to eager load (include) a private field collection with a public read only property

Tags: ef-core-2.0

System.NotSupportedException : Collection is read-only.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(ExceptionResource resource)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.ClrICollectionAccessor`3.Add(Object instance, Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.AddToCollection(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigation navigation, IClrCollectionAccessor collectionAccessor, Object value)

```
public class Student 
{
     public int Id {get; private set;}
     private List<StudentProgress> _progresses;
     protected Student()
     {
        _progresses = new List<StudentProgress>();
     }
    public IEnumerable<StudentProgress> Progresses =>_progresses.AsReadOnly();
}

public class StudentProgress 
{
    public int Id {get; private set;}
    public int ProgressStatusId { get; private set; }
    public int Year { get; private set; }
    public Grade Grade { get; private set; }
    public int CourseId { get; private set; }

    public StudentProgress(Grade grade, int year, int courseId, int progress)
    {
        ProgressStatusId = progress;
        Year = year;
        Grade = grade;
        CourseId = courseId;
    }
}

public class StudentEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Student> studentConfiguration)
    {
        studentConfiguration.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        studentConfiguration.Ignore(x => x.DomainEvents);

      studentConfiguration.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Student.Progresses))
        .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new StudentEntityTypeConfiguration());
    }
}
```

this is where I'm getting the error (Repository):

```
public async Task<Student> FindAsync(int identity)
{
    var student = await _context.Set<Student>()
        .Include(x=>x.Progresses) // this line is generating the error
        .Where(b => b.Id == identity)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        return student;
}
```

Comment: Could you show your Model?

Comment: I posted my model in the question

Comment: I can't say if that was a bug which is fixed or the sample is incomplete, but with EF Core 2.0.1 the sample works as expected (no exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to change the way you're getting `_progresses` in my code:

```
public class Student 
{
     public int Id {get; private set;}
     private List<StudentProgress> _progresses;
     protected Student()
     {
        _progresses = new List<StudentProgress>();
     }
    public IEnumerable<StudentProgress> Progresses =>_progresses; // changed from AsReadOnly()
}
```